# How I can get number from user that includes only 5,6?

Tags: python

How I can get number from user that only includes 5 and 6?
I try for loop but it's not work,also try convert the input to string,also no work.how to do?

```
Number = int(input('enter num')
for x in number:
    if 4<x<7:
      print('ok)
    else:
      print ('no')
```

Comment: Please post the required [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  The code you have here fails from several syntax errors, and shows no attempt to debug.  Insert a `print` statement or two for tracing your variable values.  It's hard to write your own program when you aren't 100% sure what values  you have.

Comment: Why would you convert the input to string, when input is already string when it's entered?

Comment: _also try to convert to string, also no workz_ What did you try? Please provide a [mcve], and clarify what exactly the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

In python 3, `input` returns a string. You can easily filter the numbers you want with

```
val = int(''.join(c for c in input('enter num: ') if c in '56'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, why do you need a loop there and why you use x. Try this:

```
number = int(input('enter num')
if number in [5, 6]:
    print('ok)
else:
    print ('no')
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'm sure the others might work, this is yet another way to check for a specific number.

```
#Gets the number from the user
Number = int(input("Enter Num"))

#checks to see if the number is either 5 or 6
if (Number == 5 or Number == 6):
  print("ok") #if it is, it prints ok
else:
  print("No") #if it isn't, it prints no
```

Answer (score -1):

It is probably easier if you check for *digits* 5 and 6 before converting to `int`.

```
Number_str = input('enter num')
for x in Number_str:
    if not ord('4')<ord(x)<ord('7'):
        print ('no')
        break
else:
    Number = int(Number_str)
    print('ok')
```